# Design for type ambiguity

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

Looking for refactoring suggestions on the below scenario.
We have a `DataMap<header,RecordHolder>`.
The RecordHolder class has an approximate structure as follows.
RecordA,RecordB.... inherit from a common base type - Record.

```
RecordHolder{
    RecordA
    RecordB
    RecordC
    RecordD;

    setRecordA();
    setRecordB();
    ....
}
```

A parser utility reads each line of a file and translates into the corresponding record type :

```
Map<key,Record> parse(String line){....}
```

On return from parse,the RecordHolder instance corresponding to the key is to be fetched - and the appropriate setRecordXXX method has to be invoked to update the parsed record.

```
RecordHolder d = DataMap.get(key);
if(d==null){ ==========> (A)
    d = new RecorHolder();
    DataMap.put(key,d);
}
d.setRecordXXX(Record);=========>(B)
```

Questions at:
(A) Whats the best idiom for get-else-put-and-return for map.
(B) How can i achieve this without an explicit type check of Record(RecordA,RecordB etc etc)

Comment: If your records all inherit from the Record class, why wouldn't RecordHolder just have a single Record member rather than possible instances of each subclass?

Comment: What does setRecordA(), setRecordB() actually do? Does it simply assign the record to the RecordA/RecordB member? Or is there any specific logic for each different record type?

Comment: Each holder object will contain a record of each type - that accounts for the variants of the method setRecordXXX from legacy.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot store a List<Record> in your RecordHolder? Then you can have a simple setRecord(Record) method. you don't need to worry about the specific record types and it remains extensible for future.

Answer (score 3):

> (A) Whats the best idiom for get-else-put-and-return for map.

You can make use of `Map#computeIfAbsent()` method, like the following code shows:

```
DataMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new RecordHolder()).setRecordXXX(Record);
```

`computeIfAbsent` takes as the first argument the key, and as the second argument a `Function<KeyType, RecordHolder>`. So when no value for the key exists. Then the function will be invoked and set as a value.

A possible implementation in a map can be the following (Not the actual from the jdk though):

```
public V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<K,V> mappingFunction){
    V value = this.get(key);
    if(value == null){
        value = mappingFunction.apply(key);
        this.put(key, value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The Types `K` and `V` are generic and stand for the type of the `key` respectively the `value`. As you can see, the method `computeIfAbsent` returns the `value` which is either in the map or which was later created. On which then the `setRecordXXX` method can be called.

> (B) How can i achieve this without an explicit type check of Record(RecordA,RecordB etc etc)

For that you'd have to create a method in RecordHolder which uses an `if-elseif-else-statement` to determine what record should be set. Like the following:

```
public void setRecordXXX(Record record){
    if(record instanceof RecordA){
        setRecordA((RecordA) record);
    } else if(record instanceof RecordB){
        setRecordB((RecordB) record);        
    } else if(...){
        // other records
    } else {
        // throw when unknown record implementation
        throw new UnsupportedOperation("RecordType not supported: " + record);
    }
}
```